# Error says: " Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function". I am guessing the error is due to react-hook-form update. Does anyone know this?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I am wondering how I can solve this with new ways of coding.
I heard someone says this error is due to the update of react-hook-form, but I am not sure how to solve this. if anyone knows this I will really appreciate it.

the error says: " Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function"
I am using  "react-hook-form": "^7.3.6",

```
    <textarea
      name="content"
      ref={register({
        required: { value: true, message: 'content is required' },
        maxLength: { value: 20000, message: 'content is too long' },
        minLength: { value: 10, message: 'content is too short' },
      })}
    ></textarea>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v7 the usage of `register` has changed:

```
<textarea
  {...register('content', {
    required: { value: true, message: 'content is required' },
    maxLength: { value: 20000, message: 'content is too long' },
    minLength: { value: 10, message: 'content is too short' },
  })}
/>
```

Here is relevant [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/) of the documentation for more infos.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could solve this completely.